# Assigning variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

```
#!/bin/sh
SUCCESS=0 
java -jar sbc.jar &
while [ true ];
do
echo "sleeping"
sleep 5
echo "again"
tail -1 ~/NetBeansProjects/xyz/dist/newlog.log | grep -q "[INFO ] - Stream closed"
if  [ $? = 1 ]
then
echo " entered if "
java -jar sbc.jar &
else 
echo " did not if "
fi
done
```

I want to use a better variable than $? to store the result of the previous line because I may need it more than once. The script is intended to check the last line of the file `newlog.log` for a particualr string and then start `sbc.jar` again because the string confirms that the program has stopped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in another variable:

```
...
tail -1 ~/NetBeansProjects/xyz/dist/newlog.log | grep -q "[INFO ] - Stream closed"
RES=$?
if  [ $RES = 1 ]
...
```

Comment: Thanks. I was giving a space after RES earlier which was making it an unknown variable. Whitespaces are an issue with shell scripting :P . Thanks a lot :)

Comment: You're welcome. I often made that mistake. The other most common one for me was not leaving a space after [ and before ] for conditionals. Please accept this answer to save other people time.

Comment: that I figured out yesterday :D

Comment: I would have accepted it. It was showing 5 minutes are too less to accept. Done now! :)